# plaidml installation on Windows10

Tags: anaconda

I am attempting to install plaidML on a Windows 10 (home) PC with an Nvidia gtx 1070 GPU. I've installed the latest version of Anaconda, which is working ok. I then use pip to install plaidML. I get the following error when executing plaidML-setup. I've tried uninstalling/re-installing, trying different versions of Anaconda, Python and plaidML. All result in the same error message. I have had plaidML running OK on my laptop - also Win10 Home etc.

I except there's some dependency issue, but can't figure it out. I'd be very grateful for any suggestions!

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\users\benli\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)

File "c:\users\benli\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)

File "C:\Users\benli\Anaconda3\Scripts\plaidml-setup.exe_main.py", line 9, in

File "c:\users\benli\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plaidml\plaidml_setup.py", line 44, in main
devices, _ = plaidml.devices(ctx, limit=100, return_all=True)

File "c:\users\benli\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plaidml_init.py", line 1057, in devices
enumerator = Enumerator(ctx)

File "c:\users\benli\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plaidml_init.py", line 1016, in init
ctx, ctypes.cast(None, _ENUM_DEVICES_FUNCTYPE), None)

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000010

Answer (score 0):

Try running your cmd prompt as admin. (Right click on anaconda prompt, click run as admin)